# Left align both list numbers and text

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I'd like to left align both the numbers and the text in my `<ol>`. This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

For now, each `<li>` contains an `<a>`, but that can change. So far I tried putting left padding and then a text-indent on the `<a>`.

Here is my code as of now.

HTML:

```
<ol class="dinosaurs">
    <li><a>Dinosaur</a></li>
    <li><a>Tyrannosaurus</a></li>
    <li><a>Camptosaurus</a></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
.dinosaurs{
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

NOTE: I'm viewing the webpage in Chrome 23 on Windows 7.

Comment: Isn't this already what you're doing? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LRV5x/1/

Comment: @j08691 No. Look at the difference between where the text begins in #9 and #10.

Comment: So removing the list style position rule isn't what you need either? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LRV5x/2/

Comment: @j08691 No. That right aligns the numbers. I want both the numbers and the text to be left aligned. See the picture included in the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could position the list elements like so:

```
    .dinosaurs {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.dinosaurs li{
  position: relative;
}
.dinosaurs li a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
}
```

which would yield http://jsfiddle.net/wBjud/2/

Comment: This should not be the best accepted answer. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14347551/6086226) should.

Answer (score 27):

This seems to work:

```
.dinosaurs { counter-reset: item }
.dinosaurs li { display: block }
.dinosaurs li:before { 
  content: counter(item) ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  width: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Really nice to see a flexible solution here.  This one won't break like the solutions using absolute positioning if the elements wrap.

Comment: @cimmanon I can get this one to work a little better (what ford showed doesn't work so well for lists with wrapping text) by setting the LI to position:relative; and the :before to position:absolute; and positioning it that way. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NU48L/)

Comment: @BartS. I just logged in to say thank you. I think this should be the answer. Great!

Answer (score 6):

None of the existing answers worked for me, but by combining and building on them I found similar method that does, including for multiline entries, without requiring any tags inside list items:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
li {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1.7em;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(item) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -1.7em;
}
```

Which looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/b3dayLzo/

I think it works by putting the `li:before` in the left margin of the `li`.

You may want a different `margin-left`.

There's no class on the `ol` because in my case this appears within the style of the container.

Comment: This is the most correct answer here.  Works better than both the accepted answer and highest voted answer.  Well done!

Comment: I'd vote for this to be the accepted answer, since it's more robust and works for multi line content too.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `padding-left: 0;` to your style, and changing `list-style-position:` to `outside` if necessary.

Comment: Ah, The screenshot wasn't up yet. Keep in mind that list-style-position isn't aligning the numbers so much as it's telling the list where to appear in relation to its bounding box. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-position

Answer (score 1):

You can fake it by using positioning, padding and margins.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LRV5x/3/)**

```
.dinosaurs {
  list-style-position: inside;
  position:relative;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
a {
  position:absolute;
  left:70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `list-style-position: inside;` the number is placed inside the block of text. To adjust the position of the number and keep ident of the text use this css.

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: step-counter;
  padding-inline-start: 25px;
}
ol > li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
}
ol > li:before {
  content: counter(step-counter)".";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

To keep your bullets also to the left

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-inline-start: 25px;
}
ul > li:before {
  content: '\25cf';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```