# Left align both list numbers and LONG text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to follow this answer to left align numbers and text in an ordered list for a navigation menu:

[Left align both list numbers and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347290/left-align-both-list-numbers-and-text)

Except I have a border around the ordered list and I'd like the list to fit within the border but still be aligned properly.  My problem is if the li content is long, it will overflow/overlap into the li item below it.  For instance, this is my fiddler version of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/jimmyzaas/36ftkLLq/5/

code:

```
.fixedwidth{
width: 200px;
    background-color: #eee; 
}
.dinosaurs {
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: auto;
}

.dinosaurs li{
   position: relative;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
   padding: 3px;

}
.dinosaurs li a {
   position: absolute;
   left: 30px;
}
```

How can I have the li auto adjust height to a, without overlapping each other while using absolute positioning?  Any suggestions?  I can set a fixed height for the li but that would make all other li content unnecessarily high.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dinosaurs li {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    //overflow-x: auto;
}
```

You can use `overflow-x: hidden;` or `overflow-x: auto;`

`auto` will cause scroll bars to appear while `hidden` just hides the overflow.

Comment: I don't think overflow:hidden can be used because it will end up hiding the content.  overflow:auto also will not work since it causes scroll bars to appear.