# left align lists in reveal presentations

Tags: css, reveal.js

In a [reveal](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) presentation using the default [black.css](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/css/theme/black.css) theme, I'd like to left align the presentation.

Using a local.css I can left align the text via

```
.reveal p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

But I am not able to left align lists.

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347290/left-align-both-list-numbers-and-text) I've tried to put

```
.reveal li { display: block }
.reveal li:before {
  content: counter(item) ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  width: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

into my local.css, but that did not help.

EDIT: Added Example

[Here](http://pastebin.com/G3MWjgpj) is a minimal example with my [local.css](http://pastebin.com/QWyY2CFN) demonstrating the missing alignment of the list.

Comment: Do you have an example of your working code?

Comment: @Andrew see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  Turns out to be easy.  Changing the `display` property of `ul|ol|dl` from `inline-block` to `block` solved my problem.

I added this to my `local.css`:

```
.reveal ol,
.reveal dl,
.reveal ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 1em; }
```